# How to properly set URL rewrite rules for a php script to only accept POST

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a rewrite rule for GET and POST:

```
<LocationMatch "^/my/script/dir/?$">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|GET)$


    RewriteRule .* /resources/scripts/storage/admin/list.php


    Script POST /resources/scripts/storage/admin/create.php
</LocationMatch>
```

How would I modify it to only allow POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

50% confidence on this:

replace

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(HEAD|GET)$
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^POST$
```

don't forget:

^ has two purposes, when used inside of [ ] it designates 'not'. (EG [^0-9] would match any character that is not 0 to 9 and [^abc] would match any character that is not a lowercase a, b, or c.) When used at the beginning of a pattern in mod_rewrite, it also designates the begining of a 'line'.